# custom filter charts in chart.js

Tags: filter, chart.js, legend, items

I am developing a web application using chart.js library. I am trying to add a custom filter for charts when the user clicks on legend's checkboxes. However I don't know how to configure chart.js to call my custom filter.

For example here are the charts of my application
[image]

Then I click on Temperature's checkbox and Temperature chart is hidden

[image]

When I cliked on Temperature's checkbox, Chart.js called his default on click function to filter the charts.

I have defined my own filter function :

```
  public newLegendClickHandler(e, legendItem) {
let index = legendItem.datasetIndex;

let ci = this.chart;
[ci.getDatasetMeta(0),
ci.getDatasetMeta(1),
ci.getDatasetMeta(2)].forEach(function (meta) {
  meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null ? !ci.data.datasets[index].hidden : null;
});
ci.update();
```

}

When I click on a checkbox I would like to call this function and not Chart.js default filter function.

I have already read chart.js documentation "Custom On Click Actions" and, I don't understand why the legend attribute is empty in the example given by Chart.js team.

If you know how to replace default onclick function for legend items, I will be glad to know the solution :)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the native [**`onClick`**](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#configuration-options) event handler method of the legend.

So.. in your chart options, define the following :

```
options: {
   legend: {
      onClick: newLegendClickHandler
   },
   ...
}
```

this will override the default on-click event handler function of the legend.

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'LINE',
         data: [3, 1, 4],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.2)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.6)'
      }]
   },
   options: {
      legend: {
         onClick: newLegendClickHandler
      }
   }
});

function newLegendClickHandler() {
   alert('newLegendClickHandler function has been called!');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you! The attribute onClick solves my problem :)

Comment: Is there any way to have the default onclick behavior as well?